# Is there a simple way to remove a TimeSeries from a displayed JFreeChart Chart?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jfreechart

I have a Swing application which uses JFreeChart to display one of a series of queries. Some of these queries have a composite TimeSeries key. Each component of this key can contain a few values, but when rendered makes a very noisy graph. I would like a simple way for the users to hide/show some of the TimeSeries in the displayed Chart component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the [setSeriesVisible](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/AbstractRenderer.html#setSeriesVisible(java.lang.Boolean)) method of AbstractRenderer is what you're looking for. Although this [forum](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=21999&highlight=&sid=45b7aa7cd39577633e555cb3978b1ca4) discussion suggests that it may only work in the latest release but there's a work around for earlier releases.

Comment: The setSeriesVisible method was not one hundred percent of my answer, but you came close. I also needed to query the displayed chart to find out which series contained the key or key components I needed to hide.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean, but if you want to keep item shapes apart, have a look at the `AnalysisXYItemRenderer` class (or corresponding). There's a `transXDiff` there that can be used for such calculations (such as accumulating the diff and only show plot shapes when that accumulated value reaches a limit).

It was a couple of years ago I did this, so things might have changed in JFreeChart since then.